# Can I config Nx generators per project/lib?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I have several projects and libraries in angular Nx. In the global `nx.json` file I have the following setting:

```json
"generators": {
  "@nrwl/anglar:component": {
    "style": "scss"
  }
}
```

can i overwrite it per single library? For example, I would like my ui component library to generate components with **OnPush** changedetection.

I'm trying to find it in the documentation but I only found making my own generators which is overkill in my opinion in this case.